# How to avoid thread going in blocked state if coroutine is getting blocked

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, blocking, coroutine

I am experimenting with coroutines, Boost.Fiber and threads.
My question is, if i run a coroutine or a Fiber on a thread, and the thread gets blocked or suspended by the OS/ubr, how can i react to this and instead of the thread getting blocked/suspended just to switch to onother fiber/coroutine on the thread?

Answer (score 0):

What is  "the OS/ubr"? It's very simple. If the OS decides to stop scheduling your processes' threads, it won't run. OS is is boss.

As long as your threads get scheduled, coroutines do manage themselves, like they always do: *co-operative routines*